Not able to send the GET request through microcontroller
I want to send a GET request to a server, so I connected the microcontroller (STM32) with an Ethernet module, as the microcontroller does not have a built-in Ethernet feature. I am using these two libraries: #include "stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h" and #include "stm32f4xx_hal.h".
I have also tried adding a breakpoint but still the same result.
My GET string is:
char http_get_request[] = "GET /testX HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: IP address:port\r\n\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/4.0\r\nAccept: /\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n"; 
However, I face an issue when debugging the program:

"Break at address '0xe' with no debug information available, or outside of program code."

The number '0xe' changes repeatedly when I try to debug the program again and again (0x0, 0x10, 0xfceaf000).
Could anyone help me resolve this error?
Init:
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h" 

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2; 
void SystemClock_Config(void); 
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void); 
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void); 
void send_command(char* command); 
void send_get_request(void); 
void delay(uint32_t milliseconds){ HAL_Delay(milliseconds); }; 



Which Ethernet module? Also, you need to post the initialization routine.

HTTP requests have two newlines after the headers (i.e: \r\n\r\n). It's unlikely you'll be able to just send a plain HTTP request to "an Ethernet Module" without some form of control to establish a TCP connection first (AT commands perhaps?). If your application goes "into the weeds" (i.e: PC finds itself in strange places like 0xe), then you've likely got an issue with your handling of pointers, out of bounds writes, stack corruption, etc... it's very difficult to say without more details!

Have you tried setting a breakpoint before the suspicious code and then stepping through it?

There's a \r\n\r\n in the center of your GET request. That double CRLFCRLF ends the header. Everything after it is part of the body by definition. If you want to add more header fields as you did, you have to move that CRLFCRLF to the very end.

I already configured the ethernet module through AT commands. and i also try to solve through adding break points.
#include "main.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include "stm32f4xx_hal_uart.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
void send_command(char* command);
void send_get_request(void);
void delay(uint32_t milliseconds){
HAL_Delay(milliseconds);
};

This error is often caused by using an uninitialized pointer and has nothing to do with HTTP.

That code snippet you've marked as 'Init' has nothing to do with the initialization.
